# Fast way to deal with lintian warnings

Tags: debian, package, lintian

I'm packaging some libraries for the Mingw64 on my computer. In order to make everything portable I decided to use dpkg as package manager. As the mingw libraries are installed in `/usr/$arch-mingw-w64` I use this prefix for all windows-Stuff. Now, lintian complains about files in unusual places e.g. about DLLs and scripts in `/usr/$arch-mingw-w64/bin`. According to Windows rules (and wine rules, too) the DLLs must be in the search path. In the original MingW environment they are in the `…/bin` and some scripts should be reachable only from inside a Windows environment (aka Wine).

So I have to silence the lintian warnings somehow. From the documentation I didn't really understand, how it works. Via trial and error I found out, that messages of the form “package: warning parameter” can be copied verbatim into `debian/package.lintian-overrides`, omitting the part `package:`.

As building the package wtih debuild sometimes takes a lot of time and since the lintian overrides do not influence the build process, I'd like to have a **fast** way to test my changes of the overrides. I tried `make -f debian/rules`, but this did not work.

Comment: You should put things under `/usr/lib/$arch-ming-w64`. Don't create a new directory under `/usr`. Creating a new directory isn't really harmful, except in that it's non-standard and so causes you to surprise administrators and tools that check that administrators won't hate you.

Comment: Again: As I already wrote, the mingw-w64 libraries and includes are installed under `/usr/$arch-mingw-w64`. So installing anything under `/usr/lib/$arch-mingw-w64` would surprise the administrators much more, because the standard is defined already by the mingw-compiler.
Nevertheless, I don't see how this change would avoid all additional lintian overrides, as neither lintian nor debian has been made with windows programs in mind.
Note: None of the MingW architectures is an official Debian archtecture.
BTW: the system is called “mingw-w64”, not “ming-w64” (corrected in the question).